# Installing solarized theme for Vim (OS X 10, Terminal, Tmux)

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm installing the solarized theme for my terminal and vim. I've successfully switched to it for my Terminal (& Tmux), having imported the solarized theme for Terminal. However, I get the following layout for Vim:

[image: VIM]

Any ideas as to what might be the issue?

My .vimrc is:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle                                         
call vundle#rc()
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'     
Bundle 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'                             

filetype plugin indent on                                             

set number

syntax enable                                                         
set background=dark                                                   
let g:solarized_termcolors = 256                                      
colorscheme solarized 

set shiftwidth=4                                             
set expandtab
set notimeout                                                         
set ttimeout                                                          
set timeoutlen=100
```

The only color related lines in my bash_profile are (for ls and diff):

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=Exfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
function diff {
    colordiff -u "$@" | less -RF
}
newtext=green
oldtext=red
diffstuff=cyan
```

Finally, I've selected xterm-256 color in my terminal advanced settings.

Answer (score 1):

In vim, you should probably

```
:set t_Co=256
```

Also, for tmux you want terminal type `screen-256color`, not `xterm-256color`.